# Checking array data in sql condition PHP

Tags: php, sql

I would like to UPDATE the `seat_status` to active by checking two conditions.

> 1st condition = bus_id
>
> 2nd condition = seat_title

I'm using this code in function `cancelbook`.

```
function cancelbook($conn,$id,$busid)
{
    $stmtgetseats = $conn->prepare("SELECT seat_no from tbl_seats WHERE bus_id=:bus_id");
    $stmtgetseats->bindParam(':bus_id',$busid);
    $stmtgetseats->execute();
    $seat_no=$stmtgetseats->fetchAll();
    for($i=0;$i<count($seat_no);$i++)
    {
        $stmtactive = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_busseats SET seat_status='active' WHERE bus_id=:bus_id AND seat_title=:seat_title");
        $stmtactive->bindParam('bus_id',$busid);
        $stmtactive->bindParam('seat_title',$seat_no[$i]);
    }
    if ($stmtactive->execute()) {
        exit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

im getting this error
Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: the last if statement doesn't look right !, `exit()` will terminate script execution, did you mean `if ($stmtactive->execute()) return true; return false;`

Comment: in which line ? please provide the full notice

Comment: I exited to check error

Comment: The error is from line where the seat_title is binded

Comment: which means that `$seat_no[$i]` is not a string but an array, can you do a `var_dump($seat_no);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you did the loop will only update one row, to update every row you should execute your statement for each iteration.

```
function cancelbook($conn,$id,$busid)
{
    $stmtgetseats = $conn->prepare("SELECT seat_no from tbl_seats 
                                    WHERE bus_id=:bus_id");
    $stmtgetseats->bindParam(':bus_id',$busid);
    $stmtgetseats->execute();
    $seat_no=$stmtgetseats->fetchAll();
    foreach($seat_no as $seat) {
        $stmtactive = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_busseats SET seat_status='active' 
                                      WHERE bus_id=:bus_id 
                                      AND seat_title=:seat_title");
        $stmtactive->bindParam('bus_id',$busid);
        $stmtactive->bindParam('seat_title',$seat['seat_no']);
        $stmtactive->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need to keep track of the number of successful updates and failures, i'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: what is difference between your solution and mine?

Comment: read the OP's question and my answer, i'm sure you'll figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems `$seat_no[$i]` is not string and it's an array , (I suggest `var_dump($seat_no[$i]);` it before), my quess  is it should be something the following snippet:

use

`$stmtactive->bindParam('seat_title',$seat_no[$i]['seat_no']);`

instead of

```
$stmtactive->bindParam('seat_title',$seat_no[$i]);
```

in your code will resolved your problem.

of course, it's better instead of using **for**  learn to use **foreach**

**But another solution with better performance is using just one update instead of serveral updates!!!**

```
function cancelbook($conn,$id,$busid)
{
    $stmtgetseats = $conn->prepare("SELECT seat_no from tbl_seats 
                                    WHERE bus_id=:bus_id");
    $stmtgetseats->bindParam(':bus_id',$busid);
    $stmtgetseats->execute();
    $seat_no=$stmtgetseats->fetchAll();
    $seat_numbers = array_values($seat_no);
    $stmtactive = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_busseats SET seat_status='active' 
                                      WHERE bus_id=:bus_id 
                                      AND seat_title IN (:seat_title"));
    $stmtactive->bindParam('bus_id',$busid);
    $stmtactive->bindParam('seat_title',implode(",",$seat_numbers));
    $stmtactive->execute();
}
```

Also, remove **Exit** in your code, it's a bad mistake in your code

Comment: i need to check value from that array to string

Comment: @SoonangRai I mean you just need this line, why I should rewrite the whole code of you?  
I answered this question before another answer but you mark that as answer!!!! why?
the solutions is the same